# Hide a Bar in BarChart with no data in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Could someone kindly help me to eliminate the bars with no data in barchart. I believe the bars with no data are holding the space in my chart and that is making my expected result look awkward with thin bars.

Comment: Welcome to SO Jazzy! Unfortunately your question has far too little detail for anyone to be able to help you so I've marked as unclear. For example the image you refer to is missing. Also you should be more specific about what charting package you're using. Finally you should include the code you've attempted so far. You can edit your own question to include all these things.

Comment: Thanks for updating me on this. Sorry to say I'm unable to post a picture.